# Efficient(-cy) at v. something else

Tags: prepositions

Should I use the proposition 'at' or some other one after the word 'efficient' or 'efficiency'? I asked a question on a different SE site, but I'm not sure whether I did it grammatically correctly. I used 'at' because of the pattern 'be good at something'.

> Which CDR options, on balance, are the most preferable in terms of feasibility and efficiency **at** long-term carbon sequestration?

Comment: in not at. in a domain or subject area. or situation.

Comment: I think I would put a comma after *feasibility*, and use *efficacy at*. Instead of the comma, you might write *efficacy at long-term carbon sequestration and feasibility*. (*preferable* has only one 'r'.)

Comment: @jacko'flaherty why is "efficiency at" bad, but "efficacy at" good?